# How shortcut string is created in a menu?

Tags: winapi

In a menu shortcut, for example: "New Ctrl+N", is the space between "New" and "Ctrl+N" created using a simple '\t' or there is a special function that takes a shortcut string and add it to the menu string?

Comment: Why do you want to know? What are you going to do with the answers?

Comment: I want to add shortcuts to my menu, so I want to know how these shortcuts are added!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's `\t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Menu_Shortcut_Keys):

> Text that identifies the shortcut key is added to the menu-item text string. The shortcut text appears to the right of the menu item name, after a backslash and tab character (\t). For example, "&Close\tAlt+F4" represents a Close command with the ALT+F4 key combination as its shortcut key and with the letter "C" as its access key. For more information, see [Keyboard Accelerators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645526(v=vs.85).aspx).